# How to change text field value without changing label value react?

Tags: reactjs

In react, I have created 2 separate variables for the label and textfield, both have the same value. I want to change the textfield value without changing the label value. I do not get why even though they are pointed to different variables, the label value still changes with the textfield value. Below is my code:

```
const PoemLine = props => (
    <Form>
         <Form.Group>
        <Row>
            <Col>
            <Form.Label column sm="8">
                {props.dataLabel[props.poemLine.line-1].text}
            </Form.Label>
            </Col>
            <Col>
            {props.poemLine.text != "" &&
                <Form.Control value={props.poemLine.text} onChange={(e) => props.onChangePoemLine(props.poemLine.line, e)}/>
            }
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
)

export default class CreateRojak extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onNext = this.onNext.bind(this);
        this.onChangeProjectAuthor = this.onChangeProjectAuthor.bind(this);
        this.onChangeProjectTitle = this.onChangeProjectTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangePoemLine = this.onChangePoemLine.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            credentialsState: true,
            projectAuthor: "",
            projectTitle: "",
            actualPoem: [], 
            dataLabel: [],
        };

    } 


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/poems/getActualPoem')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState(
                    { 
                        actualPoem: response.data[0].actualPoem,
                        dataLabel:  response.data[0].actualPoem
                    }
                )
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

I will be looping through the actualPoem array and displaying its textfield value in `PoemLine` while  using the dataLabel as the label value. My onchange only triggers the actualPoem but not the dataLabel

```
onChangePoemLine(id, e) {
        //  console.log(e)
         let tempActualPoem = [...this.state.actualPoem]
         tempActualPoem[id-1].text = e.target.value
         this.setState({
            actualPoem: tempActualPoem
         })
        //  console.log(this.state.toBeSubmittedPoem[id-1].text)
     }

     PoemLinesList() {
        //  console.log(this.state.actualPoem.actualPoem)
        return this.state.actualPoem.map(currentpoemLine => {
          return <PoemLine poemLine={currentpoemLine} dataLabel= {this.state.dataLabel} onChangePoemLine={this.onChangePoemLine} key ={currentpoemLine.line}/>;
        })
    }

render() {
 return (
            <div>
                {this.PoemLinesList()}
          </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: The two variables may appear different but in fact they are *references* to the exact same array object. Any modifications to that array will be seen in both variables

Comment: @charlietfl how can I modify my codes such that they point differently?

Comment: Will need to do a *deep copy* if you want them to be unique. Search that term

Comment: @charlietfl I modified `PoemLinesList() {
        let dataLabel = this.state.actualPoem.slice()
        return this.state.actualPoem.map(currentpoemLine => {
          return <PoemLine poemLine={currentpoemLine} dataLabel= {dataLabel} onChangePoemLine={this.onChangePoemLine} key ={currentpoemLine.line}/>;
        })
    }` but still to no avail

Comment: That shallow copies the array itself but the object references it contains are the same. A deep copy would copy the objects also

Comment: @charlietfl hmm do you mind telling me what i should add into the codeS?

Comment: Try mapping a copy before setState using `const deepCopy = dataLabel:  response.data[0].actualPoem.map(o=>({...o}))`